# Creating StrStr() Function

Tags: c

This is the code I wrote so far, but I want to make `int myStrStr` instead of `char myStrStr` But when I put `int` instead of `char`, it gives me an error. Please help.

```
int my_strlen(const char *s1) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *s1; s1++, i++);
    return i;
}

char myStrStr(char * haystack, char * needle){
    int i;
    if(*needle =='\0')
        return (char *)haystack;
    else{
        for(;*haystack; haystack++){
            if(*haystack == *needle){
                for(i=1;*(haystack +i)==*(needle +i);i++);
                if(i==my_strlen(needle))
                    return (char *)haystack;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How is `myStrStr()` called? What error does it give?

Comment: FYI `myStrStr("hogefuga", "fuga");` will result in out-of-bounds read (undefined behavior).

Comment: where is the `main`?

Comment: Is your goal to have `myStrStr` return the position in `haystack` at which `needle` is found? If so, `ptrdiff_t` is the idiomatic type to use.

Comment: Hmmm, it smells because `char*` is passed to the `return` statements in `myStrStr()` while its return value type is `char` (not a pointer).

Comment: Both `char` and `int` are wrong, since the function actually returns `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of you return `char*` or `NULL`. You cannot cast pointers to non-pointers types.
Now should be error when you compile. You function should return `char*`.

You cant cast `char*` to `int*` because of int allocate more space in memory so memory must be rellocate, this must be done manualy.